# CIP25 Metadata standard version 2 token name

Tags: native-assets, token, cip

I have seen recently that CIP25 was updated to include version 2. The main change in this is that the token name is now a `bytes` type whereas before it was a string.

My question is, what type actually is this? Is it a JavaScript Buffer, a byte array, a hex encoded string, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

On the blockchain, the token name was never actually a string and was always bytes. Usually they are ASCII encoded, but they may also be UTF8, UTF-16 or even some other encoding.